# How to access class fields in JPA Select statement?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to build JPA Query as described in [Geospatial Queries with Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial)

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(:lat_t/1E6)) ) * cos( radians( x.m_Latitude/1E6) ) ) * cos( radians( x.m_Longitude/1E6) ) - radians(:lng_t/1E6)) )  + sin( radians(:lat_t/1E6)) ) * sin( radians( x.m_Latitude/1E6) ) ) ) ) AS distance " +
            "FROM ProfileEntity x" +
            "HAVING distance < 10", ProfileEntity.class);
```

But I get:

```
Cannot find type of (part of) x.m_Latitude since symbol has no type; implicit variable?
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Cannot find type of (part of) x.m_Latitude since symbol has no type; implicit variable?
```

I guess I'm not accessing properly m_Latitude that is a field in ProfileEntity.

How can I don it?

I'm also not sure what is "id" perpeas, any ideas?

Comment: if you don't know what is "id" why would you select it? Posting ProfileEntity would be a prerequisite to anything. You have looked at the syntax of JPQL have you ? because that referenced web page is not JPQL; there are no acos(), cos(), radians() methods in JPQL